# PHP - convert arraypush to array[] =

Tags: php, arrays

I read on different posts that to push data to an array is it better to use `myarray []=` instead of `array_push()`. Eventhough I read several posts on the subject I do not see how to convert the here below code to `array[] =`. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

```
array_push($myarray, array($street, $code, $country));

myarray[] = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing :

```
$myarray[] = array($street, $code, $country);
```

would do it. [Docs on this method are here](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

The docs for `array_push` recommend :

> If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to
>   use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a
>   function.

This means that the internals of array_push are the same as doing the above call - so calling the `array_push` method to add one element is a waste !

[Docs for array_push here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Hello Manse. The thing is I am pushing ten thousands of element to my array through a foreach loop. What is the better solution in that case then?

Comment: @Marc still this method because you are only adding a single element at a time

Comment: @Marc im guessing you are using a `foreach` loop to get the values of `$street`/`$code` and `$country` each time ?

Comment: "myarray[]" needs a "$" in front.

Answer (score 4):

```
$myarray[] = array($street, $code, $country);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
$myarray[] = array($street, code, $country);
```